# C# programmatically position panel to fill one third of the parent form (WinForm)

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, position

I have a form with a Panel and a RichTextBox. The Panel is Dock.Top and the RTB is Dock.Bottom. After initialization.
I wish to position the panel so it takes up the top 1/3 of the form with the RTB taking up the remaining bottom of the form.

However, the code presented below does not work.

```
 public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            panel1.Top = 0;
            panel1.Width = this.Width;
            panel1.Height = this.Height / 3;
            ConOut.Top = panel1.Height + 10;
            ConOut.Width = this.Width;

        }
```

**Question**
1) What is wrong with the above code so that it does not position the form's controls properly?

Comment: could you tell us why you want to do it programatically? (just curiosity)

Comment: You might think of using **TableLayoutPanel** to position Panel & RTB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to add `Left` position I guess.

```
panel1.Left = 0; // Sets top left corner position
```

Complete code that could solve the problem.

```
        InitializeComponent();
        panel1.Top = 0;
        panel1.Left = 0;
        panel1.Width = this.Width;
        panel1.Height = this.Height / 3;

        ConOut.Left = 0;
        ConOut.Top = this.Height / 3;
        ConOut.Width = this.Width;
        ConOut.Height = 2*this.Height / 3;
```